# Table width in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

[image]This might be a simple question, but I'm having trouble with it: In my web page, I have the following:

```
<head>
   <!-- Stuff here -->
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
          <!-- More stuff here... -->
      </div>
   </header>
</body>
```

where `content-wrapper` is in a css file and defines `max-width: 960px`. The problem I'm having is that the `max-width` has no effect in IE8. In the body, I have a table that I thought should be limited by the width defined in the `content-wrapper`, but in IE8 it just ignores it (but it works in Firefox).

I tried a couple of different things, with no success:

- Added `style="max-width:960px"` to the
- Added `style="max-width:960px"` to the `<tr>` that is giving me grief
- Added `style="width:400px"` to the problematic `<th>` and `<td>`

None of those worked in IE! Any ideas? What am I missing?

New info:

I put my table inside a div tag like this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; width: 960px">
   <!-- Table comes here -->
</div>
```

As you see in the attached image, the div is being properly changed to have a border and the specified width, but the table just ignores it in IE8. In Firefox it works fine.

Comment: according to caniuse.com, ie8 has problems with overflow auto/scroll.

Comment: This must be the new slogan for stackoverflow: "You have the codes but you don't tell. I know what you are missing but I won't tell."

Comment: Anna, please go to jsfiddle.net and create a fiddle which we can investigate. There might be millions of reasons we can't tell it without seeing the codes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SZh3j/2/ like this

Comment: Thanks Daniel A. White. I'm not using overflow, though (I tried and didn't work properly as we would expect with IE...).

Comment: Ali Carikcioglu: the only problem is that jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8...

Comment: Anna. I updated my answer. Please check it. I added the IE6 test results as well.

Comment: Please create a fiddle on Chrome and give me the fiddle link. I will try to find the problem why it doesn't in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content-wrapper`'s container has to have a `width` along with the `max-width` in IE8 for it to recognize it.

Take a look at this article concerning IE8 and max-width:
http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/5/How-max-width-fails-in-IE8.html

Comment: Thanks, Front Ent Guyy, but this still doesn't solve the issue. My content-wrapper looks like this: .content-wrapper {margin: 0 auto; max-width: 960px; width: 960px;} Still, IE ignores it :S

Comment: I've updated your fiddle from above: http://jsfiddle.net/E9dL6/ is this the result you're looking for? (look at it in chrome)

Comment: It's so weird how nothing worked on IE8! Making the width 100% still makes the table to use 100% of the screen space, not 100% of the div where it is. Of course, everything is fine in Firefox (I hate IE...)

Comment: Ha! Gotta love (not) IE! The issue is that my XML doesn't have spaces between tags. So, if I have nested tags like <tag1><tag2><tag3>SomeValueWithoutSpaces</tag3></tag2></tag1> IE8 will not break it and then it will go over the width I establish either in the actual table or the css file. Does any of you know if there is a way to force wrapping the string in IE (I can't change the XML file to include the spaces)?

Answer (score 1):

`width: 90%` ... it works in all browsers... I tested it and show the test result below.

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SZh3j/3/)**

[image]

```
.content-wrapper
{ 
    width: 90%;
    height: 190px;
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ali, I tried that but it doesn't work as I expect: what it does is it brings the body more to the left of the screen, but I still have a lot of content being displayed to the right of the screen (that is, I still have to scroll the same way as before). Plus, this css messes up with the appearance in Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use either of them at work :( But this is another thing I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/vhtXZ/1/ (It's more or less what I have; I'm using MVC and the code is spread through many files. If I change the width in the grid from 960px to 60px, it doesn't change in my page for either Firefox or IE (even though it works in the jsfiddle). Not sure why it doesn't change...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <header>
        <style>
            .content-wrapper {
               width:450px;
               background-color: red;
               height: 250px;
            }
           .content-wrapper table {
              width: 100%;
           }
       </style>
    </header>
    <body>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column 11
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column 12
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column 13
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column 21
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column 22
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column 23
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Move the css to your css file. I think this will work